# Php Response Objective-c ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: php, request, asihttprequest

I want to send the login and password via POST, check them in DB and return an associated name if any.

To do this I have the following php:

```
<?php

class RedeemAPI {

    private $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'Xxx', 'Xxx');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method to redeem a code
    function redeem() {

      // Check for required parameters
        if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

            // Put parameters into local variables
            $user = $_POST["user"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            // Look up code in database

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT nombreCliente FROM Clientes WHERE user=? AND password=?');            
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($nombreCliente);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                break;
            }
            $stmt->close();

            // Return unlock code, encoded with JSON
            $result = array("nombreCliente" => $nombreCliente);
            sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
            return true;
        }
        sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
        return false;

    }

}

// This is the first thing that gets called when this page is loaded
// Creates a new instance of the RedeemAPI class and calls the redeem method
$api = new RedeemAPI;
$api->redeem();

?>
```

In Xcode I have the following method:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Want to redeem: %@ y %@", self.userText.text, self.passwordText.text);

    NSString *user = self.userText.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordText.text;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.200.2/php/login.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //NSURLRequest *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:user forKey:@"user"];
    [request setPostValue:password forKey:@"password"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    // first, check to see if there was an error with sendAsynchronousRequest

    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *idCliente = [responseDict objectForKey:@"nombreCliente"];

    NSLog(@"ResponseStatus = %d",request.responseStatusCode);
    NSLog(@"ResponseStatusString = %@",request.responseStatusMessage);
    NSLog(@"ResponseString = %@",responseString);
    NSLog(@"responseDict = %@", responseDict);
    NSLog(@"idCliente = %@",idCliente);
```

However, all NSLog returns to (null).

The connection to the database makes it well because I checked the POST and without the fault has to come out there

I've been looking a lot of information and many people recommend doing so but can not find what could be the exact problem.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Thank you very much to all!

Comment: All returns null...even this `NSLog(@"Want to redeem: %@ y %@", self.userText.text, self.passwordText.text);
` ??

Comment: no, sorry, that returns well.

Comment: Did you check on your Apache server that it can accept incoming connections from the local network(i.e: your intranet)...

Comment: Yes.I think the problem comes in the post method...

Comment: You could add this block `if ([request error])` and check for errors..

Comment: [request error] also is null...

Comment: Are you sure this is a php valid function `sendResponse`....btw, if you execute this directly on your browser: http://192.168.200.2/php/login.php what kind of response do you have...can you post the response image(Print Screen)?

Comment: The response is empty because it is waiting to pass the post "login" and "password". I'm not sure it's valid but I've seen on several sites and I followed the tutorial at the following link: raywenderlich.com/2941/… –  user3725901

Comment: I check the tutorial, and you are missing 2 functions: `sendResponse` and `getStatusCodeMessage`...

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one Its may be useful to you

```
-(void) list_my_product_Called
 {

   ASIFormDataRequest *request1 ;

   request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",STR_URL_login]]];

  [request1 setPostValue:appDel.UserId  forKey:@"user"];
  [request1 setPostValue:appDel.UserToken  forKey:@"password"];

  request1.timeOutSeconds = 140;

  [request1 setDelegate:self];

  // NSLog(@"request body : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request1.postBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

  [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished_login:)];
  [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed_login:)];
  [request1 startSynchronous]; 
}


 - (void)requestFinished_login:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* oDict = [json objectWithString:[request responseString]];


    NSLog(@"Signup Response oDict  = %@",oDict);

    if ([[oDict valueForKey:@"status_code"] integerValue] == 1)
    {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:[oDict valueForKey:@"message"]  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];



    return;

   }
   else
   {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fejl" message:[oDict valueForKey:@"msg"]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
      [alert show];
      return;
   }
 }

 - (void)requestFailed_login:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {
     NSLog(@"Request Failed %@",[request responseString]);


       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server        Error" message:STR_ERR_UNKNOWN  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
    return;

}
```